# How to open multiple screen named virtual terminal sessions

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen

I use Linux (GNU) screen daily.  When my machine needs to reboot, I want to be able to rebuild the screen session via a script.  I want to be able via a bash scrip to start the screen session (this I know how to do) and open multiple virtual terminals inside 1 screen session and I want the ability to label each virtual terminal individually.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer: https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Screen-Command

So I will have to build a .screenrc for each screen session I want to build and then execute screen -c for that .screenrc to start the sessions as I want.